# Error: Meme validation failed: comments.0.note: Path `note` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, liquid

note:I removed this line to test something and added it back and now I'm having validation issues with the author part of the comments sub document: `req.body.author = req.session.userId`

I'm not sure where I may have gone wrong today. After refactoring some styling, I started to play around with my controller for comments to try to setup a comment delete. After trying a few things that didn't work, I posted another comment just testing other things, sidetracking, and was met with the error below (this is parsed in the browser):

```json
"errors": {
"comments.0.note": {
"name": "ValidatorError",
"message": "Path `note` is required.",
"properties": {
"message": "Path `note` is required.",
"type": "required",
"path": "note"
},
"kind": "required",
"path": "note"
}
},
"_message": "Meme validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "Meme validation failed: comments.0.note: Path `note` is required."
}
```

I tried removing required:true from the comment schema, and then I don't get an error and I do see in my terminal that a comment was created but the html element doesn't render in the div I set up for comments. Becoming frustrated, I even checked my files with what I have in GitHub and everything is the same. I even did some copy pasting. I don't understand what I've done wrong, as this path issue was not a problem before. Other than changing required true to false after receiving the error, the comment schema has collected dust. Regardless, the code has been pasted to be the way it was before it was working, so I'm really confused here. Here's some code but let me know if you need to see anything else.

The only other thing to mention is that I opened up Postman and tried to use a get route in it. If I'm being honest, I had to step away from coding and I'm a little rusty with Postman. Is it possible I could have done something there that interfered with things? Thank you for any help. Code below:

server.js

```js
    ////////////////////
    //  Dependencies  //
    ////////////////////
    require("dotenv").config() // make env variables available
    const fetch = require('node-fetch')
    const express = require("express")
    const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
    //const ExampleRouter = require('./controllers/example')
    const UserRouter = require('./controllers/user')
    const memeRouter = require('./controllers/meme')
    const commentRouter = require('./controllers/comment')
    const User = require("./models/user")
    
    // SEE MORE DEPENDENCIES IN ./utils/middleware.js
    // user and resource routes linked in ./utils/middleware.js
    
    //////////////////////////////
    // Middleware + App Object  //
    //////////////////////////////
    const app = require("liquid-express-views")(express())
    
    middleware(app)
    
    ////////////////////
    //    Routes      //
    ////////////////////
    
    app.use('/memes', memeRouter)
    app.use('/auth', UserRouter)
    app.use('/comments', commentRouter)
    //app.use('/examples', ExampleRouter)
    
     app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        const { username, userId, loggedIn } = req.session    
                 res.render('index.liquid', {loggedIn, username, userId })
        
    })
    //api died but keeping this for reference//
    
    // app.get('/:memePage', (req, res) => {
    //     const { username, userId, loggedIn } = req.session
    //     const page = parseInt(req.params.memePage)
    //     const requestURL = `http://alpha-meme-maker.herokuapp.com/${page}`
    //      fetch(requestURL)
    //         .then(responseData => {
    //             return responseData.json()
    //         })
    //         .then(jsonMemeData => {
    //             console.log(jsonMemeData)
    //             res.render('show', {memeData: jsonMemeData, username,userId,loggedIn})
    //         })
    //         .catch(error => {
    //             res.send(error)
    //         })
    // })
    
    // app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    //     const page = req.body.page
    //     console.log('this is the page ', page)
    //     res.redirect(`/${page}`)  
        
    // })
    
    app.get('/error', (req, res) => {
        const error = req.query.error || 'This Page Does Not Exist'
        const { username, loggedIn, userId } = req.session
        res.render('error.liquid', { error, username, loggedIn, userId })
    })
    
    // if page is not found, send to error page
    app.all('*', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/error')
    })
    
    //////////////////////////////
    //      App Listener        //
    //////////////////////////////
    
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
    })
```

comment schema(sub document):

```js
    /////////////////////////////////
    // import dependencies
    /////////////////////////////////
    const mongoose = require('./connection')
    
    // here's an alternate syntax for creating a schema
    // reminder: we do not need a model for a subdocument
    // all we need is a schema 
    const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        note: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        author: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true
    })
    
    module.exports = commentSchema
```

comment controller:

```js
    const express = require('express')
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const Meme = require('../models/Meme')
    
    
    const router = express.Router()
    
    ///////////////
    //Routes
    ///////////////
    
    router.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
        const memeId = req.params.id
        console.log('first comment body', req.body)
        
        // we'll adjust req.body to include an author
        // the author's id will be the logged in user's id
        req.body.author = req.session.userId
        console.log('updated comment body', req.body)
        // we'll find the fruit with the fruitId
        Meme.findById(memeId)
            .then(meme => {
                // then we'll send req.body to the comments array
                meme.comments.push(req.body)
                // save the fruit
                return meme.save()
            })
            .then(meme => {
                // redirect
                res.redirect(`/memes/mine/${meme.id}`)
            })
            // or show an error if we have one
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                res.send(error)
            })
    })
    
    module.exports = router
```